# How to resize my entire webpage to 65%

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

My webpage is working fine while displaying on my 1920x1080 monitor.
But when I change to use 1024x768 monitor.The content of my webpage will be too big.
I used CTRL+Scroll to resize my webpage to 65% and everything seemed to be good!
Is there any code solution like CSS, javascript or etc.. to resize my entire webpage to 65%?

PS:I use Joomla to develop my website. Maybe an addon?...

Comment: Zooming functions cannot be controlled by javascript.. i think..
You should design your website to use percentage sizes, so things resize with your resolution/window size.

Comment: Wrong, it can be controlled with Javascript but it's not good practice. You should design your css using percentage units most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
    transform:scale(0.65,0.65);
    -ms-transform:scale(0.65,0.65); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.65,0.65); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

You could try wrapping the entire site in `<div class="wrapper"></div>`

Edit: This would not be best practice, but does answer your question. Ideally you should create your website using % based layout so that it re sizes automatically to any screen resolution.

Comment: Who downvoted this answer? It's the right approach and also provides helpful insight about best practices!